# Nativescript-Vue How to open file on launch

Tags: vue.js, nativescript, file-association

I have followed [this](https://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/b/stevez/posts/associate-a-file-type-with-your-ios-application) article to set up my app to open a file.  I can successfully click on the file and launch my application.  I can see the following in my console.log

(Foundation) [com.apple.foundation.filecoordination:claims] Write options: 0 -- URL: file:.......filename.........

Can someone either explain how I can access the file from my app once it launches?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You will have to write your [custom app delegate](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/application-lifecycle#ios-uiapplicationdelegate) and implement `applicationOpenURLOptions` method to access the file.

For example,

```
var MyUIApplicationDelegate = UIResponder.extend(
    {
        applicationOpenURLOptions: function(app, url, options) {
            var file = File.fromPath(url.path);
            // process the file
            return true;
        },
    },
    {
        name: "MyUIApplicationDelegate",
        protocols: [UIApplicationDelegate],
    }
);

application.ios.delegate = MyUIApplicationDelegate;
```